# MSBuild: What do I need on my build server to Build my project

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am looking to build projects on a build server (right now it is just a server but I want to use MSBuild to build projects on there).  I want to use PowerShell scripts to get my code from a repository (Doesn't matter what type), put the source into a common directory, put all dependencies into a common directory (similar to how it is build in my workspace on my local machine), build everything and put all the deployable binaries into a bin which I will be moving to the deployment directories using other Powershell scripts.

I assume I am going to have to have MSBuild installed on the server that I will doing all of this on.  Do I need to have the .Net framework installed on that server to accomplish this?  Do I just need the EXE to have this work?  Is there a good way to managed dependencies?  Should I have them in a specific folder?

Comment: Have you looked into a product like Hudson or Jenkins? It would do most of the work for you.

Comment: I have, but that is simply not possible with our current architectural direction.  Not that I agree with it, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the core .NET assemblies are stored in the Windows Global Assembly Cache (GAC). You won't have to worry about those. Yes, you'll need the Microsoft .NET Framework installed, in order to compile (build) .NET projects. I believe msbuild.exe is included with the .NET Framework, so you'll find it under a location such as: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe`.

Your PowerShell script will have to copy any external dependencies (assemblies (DLLs and EXEs), .NET resource files, image files, external binaries, etc.) to the appropriate target location after compilation, such that the software executes successfully. You'll need to work with your software development team to determine [comprehensively] what those dependencies are.

Answer (score 1):

MsBuild.exe moved, and is now part of Visual Studio as of v2013.

To get the latest version of MsBuild.exe without having to install Visual Studio 2013, download [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)